Is `Ungreedy` flag need for matching till the end of line $?
This is my Regex: ^([\p{L}]+\.?)(?:[-\s']?[\p{L}]+)*$
I would like to use it to match city names.
With test strings:
Travelers Rest
San Francisco
Three word city
abc-bbc
St. Catharines
xx's city
San Fransisco
Val-d'Or
Presqu'ile
Niagara on the Lake
Niagara-on-the-Lake
München
toronto
toRonTo
villes du Québec
Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur
Île-de-France
Kópavogur
Garðabær
Sauðárkrókur
Þorlákshöfn
上海
東京

It only finds two matches without Ungreedy flag.
Can anyone explain why this is happening?


Have you thought of city names like 'Ili'ili, Westward-Ho!, Saint-Louis-du-Ha! Ha!,...

Using \s can also match a newline and the asterisk here is greedy (?:[-\s']?[\p{L}]+)*
It can match an optional -, whitespace character or ' followed by 1+ times any kind of letter as many times as possible, which gives you the 2 matches from your example.
Note that when there is no match it could potentially lead to catastrophic backtracking due to nested quantifiers.
Using the "Ungreedy" flag makes quantifiers lazy, and as the second part is optional, only asserting the end of the string is expected to match.
That is why if you use that flag you will see that your matches are not crossing newlines as the second part is repeated as few times as possible to assert the end of the string:
^([\p{L}]+\.?)(?:[-\s']?[\p{L}]+)*$
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    Optional

You use a capture group in your regex ([\p{L}]+\.?) and a non capture group for the repetition. If you use the capture group on purpose, note that the Ungreedy flag influences the part that is being captured as it makes the quantifiers lazy and the captured value will be as short as possible.
Depending on the regex flavour that you are using, you could either match an optional dot followed by 1 or more spaces without a newline, or match one of  - or '
^\p{L}+(?:(?:\.?[^\S\n]+|[-'])[\p{L}]+)*$

See a regex demo.
Or replace \s with \h to match a horizontal whitespace char if that is supported:
^\p{L}+(?:(?:\.?\h+|[-'])[\p{L}]+)*$

See a regex demo.
If you want to use a lookaround, I would use a negative lookahead asserting the the next character directly to the right is not a newline \n or \r?\n:
^\p{L}+(?:(?:\.?(?!\n)\s+|[-'])[\p{L}]+)*$

See a regex demo.
To match the names in the comments, you might use this pattern but note that a regex will not validate a city name. A regex matches text, and for the examples in this answer a single character like A will also match.

The problem is the last part or your expression
^([\p{L}]+\.?)(?:[-\s']?[\p{L}]+)*$
                        ^^^^^^^^

Because you're using the unicode character, and also using the multiline flag /gm then this part of the regex also matches new lines followed by any other valid character in the name
To avoid this you can tell the regex to explicitly avoid new lines before this segment of the expression is matched using a negative lookbehind, like this:
^([\p{L}]+\.?)(?:[-\s']?(?<!\n)[\p{L}]+)*$

Note the (?<!\n) added. This tells the engine that there must not be a new line before this part of the match
see working example below or playground here
BTW I recommend you this the site of the link to play and debug regular expressions.


"[...] and also using the multiline flag /gm": This has nothing to do with flags, but \s, which matches \n (in all modes). There's no need for lookbehind either; [-\h'] should do the trick.

Yes you're right the multiline flag does not affect in this case. I did not know about [-\h'], it works really well, its a much cleaner solution. If you want you can post it as the answer and Ill upvote it, or may I edit mine?
